# How to copy a dictionary containing reference type for value to another dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, copy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the best way to clone/deep copy a .NET generic Dictionary<string, T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139592/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-deep-copy-a-net-generic-dictionarystring-t)

Hi there! I stuck on something and I really need help :(
So I have a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, MyClass> dict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
```

Where MyClass is some class with properties, methods and so on. When I try to copy this dictionary to another, for instance:

```
Dictionary<string, MyClass> newDict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>(dict);
```

It seems that the data is copied by reference and when I try to update any MyClass object in the newDict, the data is updated and in dict. So how can I copy one dictionary to another and when I try to update the data in the copy, the data in the original stays the same?

Thanks in advance :)
Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking to do a "deep copy."  [See Jon Skeet's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139592/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-deep-copy-a-net-generic-dictionarystring-t/139841#139841).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement a `MyClass.Clone()` function which creates copies of your instance. Then iterate thru all items in your source collection and add a clone to your target collection.

Comment: You don’t have to use `ICloneable`. In fact you might be better off without.

Comment: Okay, removed the interface requirement.

Answer (score -2):

do not try to reinvent the wheel, use something already created. For such cases I use `BLTookit`, here http://bltoolkit.net/Doc.ObjectToObject.ashx or this `AutoMapper` here http://automapper.codeplex.com/.

Comment: Rather than just posting links, you should explain how they help answer the question.