# How do I copy the content of a dictionary to an new dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, dictionary

How can I copy a `Dictionary<string, string>` to another `new Dictionary<string, string>` so that they are not the same object?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want them to be individual objects, and not references to the same object pass the source dictionary into the [destination's constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.-ctor?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_2__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IDictionary__0__1__):

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> d2 = new Dictionary<string, string>(d);
```

"so that they are not the same object."

Ambiguity abound - if you do actually want them to be references to the same object:

```
Dictionary<string, string> d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
Dictionary<string, string> d2 = d;
```

(Changing either `d` or `d2` after the above will affect both)

Comment: Just as a side note, something that tripped me up once. If you use this method to copy a static dictionary, then changes made in the copy will still effect the original

Comment: another approach could be found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139592/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-deep-copy-a-net-generic-dictionarystring-t?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 11):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> first = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            {"1", "One"},
            {"2", "Two"},
            {"3", "Three"},
            {"4", "Four"},
            {"5", "Five"},
            {"6", "Six"},
            {"7", "Seven"},
            {"8", "Eight"},
            {"9", "Nine"},
            {"0", "Zero"}
        };

        Dictionary<string, string> second = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (string key in first.Keys)
        {
            second.Add(key, first[key]);
        }

        first["1"] = "newone";
        Console.WriteLine(second["1"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

A one-line version of Amal's answer:

```
var second = first.Keys.ToDictionary(_ => _, _ => first[_]);
```

Comment: Curious: Why didn't you do this instead?  `var second = first.ToDictionary(kvp => k.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);`

Comment: When performance is not critical and I'm faced with different possibilities for syntax, I go for the version I believe is easier to read.
I believe explicitly using `first.Keys.ToDictionary(_` reads better than `first.ToDictionary(kvp=> k.Key` because it reads more fluently and the variable names are not required to describe intent (hence the use of the underscore/discard).
So mine is __the Keys of `first` as a dictionary__, then I look at the last parameter and see the values are just the values by key.
Your syntax with discards works too: `first.ToDictionary(_ => _.Key, _ => _.Value)`