# creating a generic collection of key and values in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I need something like Dictionary where dynamic can be anything from string to objects.

But when i use objects, i need to know the type of the object and then access the appropriate properties of those objects.

Is there a way WITHOUT using Reflection.

*** EDITED **

I tried to use this :

```
CloneObject<T, TU>(IDictionary<T, TU> sourceObject)
```

But if i use this, how can i access T's public fields without using reflection

Comment: A Dictionary *is* a generic collection of keys and values.  What do you want to use this for?  Can you give an example?

Comment: Also, if you want people to see your question, it's a good idea to tag it with the language you're using.

Comment: @elmugrat: thanks for the tagging. I have updated the question too. I think that this is not possible to acheive.

Comment: @saravanan: Can you clarify your question further, possibly with some samples of - ideally - how you would like this to work, and what you would use it for. I still have no idea what you're asking for, sorry.

Comment: So your trying to write a method to clone any Dictionary?  If so, then see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139592/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-deep-copy-a-net-generic-dictionarystring-t

Comment: Why do you want this?  This sounds like something that might well be simpler to solve by avoiding the need in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using reflection, this task cannot be completed. All I have done is create clones of objects separately and then used them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Hashtable for this purpose

Here is the Examples

http://www.dotnetperls.com/hashtable

You can also use Dictionary which is more efficient than Hashtable

See Examples Here:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/dictionary-keys

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused a little bit. You trying to store any types of objects in your dictionary but access to them without reflection.

If so you can use `dynamic` types:

Dictionary dict = new Dictionary();

```
dict["string"] = "some string";
dict["int"] = 25;
dict["my_class"] = new MyClass {SomeProperty = 12};
```

And then you can access all this values without any casts:

```
string s1 = dict["string"].Substring(0, 4); // s1 equals to "some"
int propertyValue = dict["my_class"].SomeProperty; // propertyValue equals to 12
```

where MyClass is:

```
class MyClass
{
  public int SomeProperty {get;set;}
}
```