# cloning a dictionary that has List as values

Tags: c#, .net, cloning

how do you clone a dictionary such as this one :

```
Dictionary<int, List<User>>()
```

Every attempt that I make of cloning it ends up failing.

If I have this :

```
Dictionary<int, List<User>> dict1 = new Dictionary<int, List<User>>();
User user1=new User{Name="Mey"};
dict1.Add(1,user1);
```

doing this :

```
var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, List<User>>(dict1);
```

dict2 will still be referencing user1 instead of a new User object.

I want the User object to be duplicated so that changing the clone properties is not reflected on the original object.

**Edit :**

So I wrote the following code snippet :

```
        var dict2 = new Dictionary<int, List<User>>();

        //clone the dict1 dictionary
        foreach (var item in dict1)
        {
            var list = new List<User>();
            foreach (var u in item.Value)
            {
                list.Add(new User{ Name = u.Name, Total=u.Total}); 
            }
            dict2.Add(item.Key, list);
        }

     class User
     { 
        public string Name{get;set;}
        public double Total{get;set;}
     }
```

Comment: hmmm... I mean a dictionary such as this one Dictionary<int,List<User>>

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? What does "failing" mean ? Any error messages/exceptions ?

Comment: I can't seem to enter this (Dictionary<int,List<User>>) in the body of the question. :(

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139592/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-deep-copy-a-net-generic-dictionarystring-t) something similar was asked

Comment: You need to mark it as code by wraping it in `s.

Comment: What do you want the List refer to? The exact same User objects (so changing the properties in the clones also changes the original) or a duplicate so that changing the clones won't change the original?

Comment: @Martheen, I want a duplicate. changing the clone should not change the original.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.Net collections do not have built-in cloning support.

You need to create a new dictionary, loop through all of the entries in the original dictionary, add a corresponding entry with a new `List<User>` in the new dictionary, and loop through the original list to add copies of the `User` objects to the new list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BinaryFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

1) **Serialize** your object into a MemoryStream

therefore

2) **Deserialize** MemoryStream to a new object