# nested dictionaries

Tags: vb.net

I've got a nested dict like:

```
 Public collectionMain As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, String))
```

When inserting a new item:

```
collectionMain.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("key").InnerText.Trim, collectionSub)
collectionSub.Clear()
```

On the add my collectionSub is filled with key & values.
But when calling clear, the collectionMain.value is empty.

How can i keep the collectionMain dictionary value?

The collectionSub needs to be cleared, it's in a loop for filling.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a `New` Dictionary(Of String, String) for each value.

Comment: How do you mean? create a NEW collectionSub for every dictionary that  i need in the collectionmain value? It's in a loop, and I don't know how many collectionSubs I need.

Comment: @TomVD: Create a `New Dictionary(Of String, String)()` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add a new dictionary item, you will have to declare a new sub-dictionary for that key:

```
collectionMain.Add(node.SelectSingleNode("key").InnerText.Trim, _
                   New Dictionary(Of String, String))
```

The `collectionSub` variable really should not exist since every key in `collectionMain` has it's own dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Do not clear `collectionSub`. Don't forget that you are adding reference of `Dictionary(Of String, String)`  - collectionSub. If you want to clear that object then you must have to create a "clone" (deep copy) of `collectionSub`. Take a look at SO thread - [What is the best way to clone/deep copy a .NET generic Dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139592/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-deep-copy-a-net-generic-dictionarystring-t)