# Making a method return an object by value?

Tags: c#, methods, return-by-value

I have a dictionary such that: `Dictionary<string, SomeClass> template`

Basically, what I want to do is get a *copy* of the object contained in `template`. However, I can't seem to create a method that will retrieve the object by value. I am aware of **ref** and **out**, but these are the exact opposite of what I want. A struct would be perfect, but unfortunately, `SomeClass` must inherit from another class and/or an interface.

Is there some way to do what I want? This seems like it should be really simple.

Comment: You can copy the object yourself, and pass the reference to the copy back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/139592/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-deep-copy-a-net-generic-dictionarystring-t

Comment: Agree with comment above.  C# returns object types by ref.  If you want a copy to manipulate, its on you to create a copy.

Comment: So basically, I just have to manually invoke `new SomeClass()` and manually populate all the data from another instance of SomeClass?

Comment: [Ignoring details of autocopying methods] In one form or another, yes. You might consider returning a new copy of SomeClass for any method that mutates state and not allow any setters on properties. Then you effectively have an immutable SomeClass, but the fact remains you will still need to copy SomeClass in one form or another yourself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would need a [copy constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173116%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

You can also implement [ICloneable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icloneable.aspx)  interface or create your own interface

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345389/copy-constructor-versus-clone) would also help you!