# Dictionary Constructor: System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, dictionary

A cache is initialized from another using the regular Dictionary constructor. for the first time, I get a

> System.ArgumentException : An item with the same key has already been added.

```
private Dictionary<uint, Dictionary<ClassA, ClassB>> cache;
private void updateCache(Dictionary<uint, Dictionary<ClassA, ClassB>> otherCache) 
{
  cache = new Dictionary<uint, Dictionary<ClassA, ClassB>>(otherCache); // Raises the exception
}
```

I verified that cache and othercache really have the same type.

How is this even possible ?!

Comment: Its not, unless the other cache ha inherited from dictionary which allows for duplciates. Can you do a GroupBy key and Count, and see which key is causing it to throw?

Comment: Linq does not work in the Immediate window. I'll try modifying the code (which is not mine)

Comment: yes, you need to figure out how a duplicate got into `otherCache`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/139626/442444

Comment: Have you checked that "otherCache" has the default comparer?

Comment: @YohDeadfall Another `uint` comparer can't possibly be *less* restrictive than the default comparer, can it?

Comment: @YohDeadfall Interesting! I didn't even known you could [initialize a dictionary with a custom `IEqualityComparer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Rawling Another `uint` comparer may contain a bug which allows to have two equal keys, I think.