# How should I make a deep copy of a Dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary, clone, deep-copy

What is the best way to make a deep copy of a Dictionary?  I can use one of Jon Skeet's answers ([What is the best way to clone/deep copy a .NET generic Dictionary<string, T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/139592/what-is-the-best-way-to-clone-deep-copy-a-net-generic-dictionarystring-t)), but those answers are 8 years old.  So nearly a decade later, is that still the best approach, or is there a better way?

Comment: dictionary implementation is still same, so that is the right way still

Comment: I think it is obvious that the old method is a good one.

Comment: Yes, the approach is still valid.  Nothing has changed about dictionaries, no new method that I've seen improves on Jon's answer.